# Munin - alert on monitored system downtime

Tags: linux, munin

I do monitoring for ~10 servers using munin, munin itself runs on a dedicated VPS only for this purpose. I'd like to be notified when one of my systems are down. Alerts are already configured, if disk utilization is too high for example, I receive notifications, it works like a charm. Am I able to configure such alert that's triggered when a monitored server did not report any data for 10-20 minutes for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At bird eye view, Munin is for historical trends, Nagios or similar tool is more suited to have such alerts. So Nagios can do it as a self-hosted way, pingdom.com, uptimerobot.com, etc can do it in the cloud. Munin is not really suitable for this.